# Using a script for a .desktop file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, startup, systemd

I have a couple of .desktop files which spawn terminals on startup but I want to add a script to one of these .desktop files

**Background**

```
11:39:22 - ~ - martin$ cd ~/.config/autostart/
11:39:33 - ~/.config/autostart - martin$ ls -l terminal_left_big.desktop left_terminal.sh 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 martin martin 196 юли 22 11:04 left_terminal.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 martin martin 294 юли 22 11:28 terminal_left_big.desktop
```

.desktop file

```
11:39:52 - ~/.config/autostart - martin$ cat terminal_left_big.desktop left_terminal.sh 
    [Desktop Entry]
    Type=Application
    Name=left_big
    Exec=xfce4-terminal --geometry 94x51+0+0 --title asd -H -x sh -c "toilet concerts; cat /home/martin/scrape_file/tmp.json | jq -c '.[] | select( .event_country | contains("Bulgaria"))' | jq; toilet weather;curl http://wttr.in/Sofia";
    Terminal=true
```

.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

toilet concerts
path=/home/martin/scrape_file/tmp.json 

cat $path | jq -c '.[] | select( .event_country | contains("Bulgaria"))' | jq

toilet weather

curl http://wttr.in/Sofia
exit
```

So right now my .desktop file is almost working but I replace the `-x sh -c "commans"` with `-x sh script.sh` or `-x sh ./script.sh`:

```
11:39:52 - ~/.config/autostart - martin$ cat terminal_left_big.desktop left_terminal.sh 
    [Desktop Entry]
    Type=Application
    Name=left_big
    Exec=xfce4-terminal --geometry 94x51+0+0 --title asd -H -x sh left_terminal.sh ;
    Terminal=true
```

I get this error:

```
sh: 0: Can't open left_terminal.sh
```

**Question**

I have an +x privilage for both files for all users. I don't think there 
are errors in these scripts, what is the problem?

**EDIT:**

When I add absolute path to the shell script:

```
sh: 0: Can't open /home/martin/.config/autostart/left_terminal.sh;
```

**Answer**

The semicolon must be removed
`Exec=xfce4-terminal --geometry 94x51+0+0 --title asd -H -x sh left_terminal.sh;` -> `Exec=xfce4-terminal --geometry 94x51+0+0 --title asd -H -x sh left_terminal.sh`

Comment: Use the full path to the script file.

Comment: @muru I've added an edit, but the problem is the same

Comment: Please remove the semicolon at the end. A desktop file isn't a shell script and doesn't support shell syntax.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to your question but rather add a real answer. That way people see that you already have your answer

Comment: I expected someone to do that instead of me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon must be removed

```
Exec=xfce4-terminal --geometry 94x51+0+0 --title asd -H -x sh left_terminal.sh;
```

should instead be:

```
Exec=xfce4-terminal --geometry 94x51+0+0 --title asd -H -x sh left_terminal.sh
```